# Granting authorization for WebDeploy

Tags: webdeploy

I'm able to 'one-click' publish to my remote (server 08) when using the native 'Administrator' account. I'm trying to grant a different windows account ability to remote deploy. Attempting to 'connect to site' from IIS's Start page to test the account's access will always return:

Cannot connect to the specified computer.
The remote server returned 401 Unauthorized.

For sake of testing I have this user as a member of Admin Group.

What else should I be trying?

Answer (score 0):

The following article has some useful information on installing & configuring web deploy. Could be a few different areas, so worth following through the steps to check you have it setup right:

[Installing and Configuring Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy)